# Nexus 5 Location has not updated for months?

Tags: nexus-5, geolocation

I have a Nexus 5 running on 5.1.1 but the location has not updated for the past couple months, traveled out of town but still in-state, then came back and the city never updated, so now Google Now doesn't display the current weather and things like Yahoo Weather show either the wrong location or no location.

Tried to find fixes online but most posts are out of date or about some other issue related to location, the phone's location simply isn't updating at all. This also makes things like Google Maps and Navigation useless.

Would appreciate any help, again it's just stock Android and I don't have a ton of experience flashing the OS or changing these settings.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just figured it out. For some reason I had Location set to "Device only" and the subtext below this says "Use GPS to determine your location." Seems like this should still update the location, but like I said in my question, it simply hadn't updated the current city for months.

**SOLUTION:**
**Fixed it simply by switching to "Battery saving" mode. Obviously "High accuracy" would work too.**

I'm not sure why the GPS feature under "Device only" wouldn't be able to find my location, maybe my GPS component is malfunctioning. Either way, it's fixed now.